# Spring Security : Problem with the back button

Tags: java, spring-security, logout, back-button

I am trying to use the logout functionality provided by Spring security.

The logging out works fine. The session gets invalidated(by calling **logout** method in **SecurityContextLogoutHandler** class). The user is redirected to the login page.

However, when I press the back button, I see the below code having a valid session id.The 
req.getRequestedSessionId() is **NOT** null. A **New** session is created.

```
      if (req.getRequestedSessionId() != null && 
            !req.isRequestedSessionIdValid())
        {
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
           return;
        }
```

We also have the following code in the **LogoutFilter**.

```
          HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        resp.setHeader("Expires", "Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
        resp.setHeader("Last-Modified", new Date().toString());
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache,
                                    must-revalidate, max-age=0, 
                                    post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Is it some problem with browser? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are user session still contains any data, stored before logging out, or it's empty?

Comment: A new session is created when back button is clicked. I have modified the question to include this fact.

Comment: Hm, if it's an new session (mean it doesn't contains any data of previously logged in user), what problem do you have?

Comment: There is no problem. But my requirement says me to display, "your session has expired.Login again".

Comment: well, but what the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The servlet API have two methods for getting session from a request:

[getSession()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29)

and

[getSession(boolean create)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)

The first method always return a session, creating new if one doesn't exist. The second method can be used to control whether or not a new session should be created if none exists.

Having said that, I think this is not much of an issue. An empty session usually have no impact on application's security or anything else (apart from a small memory footprint).

---

**EDIT:**

It is possible that during the logout procedure some redirect caused another request which established a new session. IF you really want to track it down, use firebug or similar tool to track all the requests in logout sequence and compare jsessionid cookie on each of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to achieve this check is probably verifying the [`SecurityContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html), instead of the [`HttpSession`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) in your Filter.